# Coeficientes de uma regressão logistica

Tags: python

Gostaria de saber como mostrar a tabela de estatisticas dos coefiencientes das variaveis independentes de um modelo de regressao logistica, na biblioteca sklearn

Comment: `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.coef_` não funciona?

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida, era exatamente o que eu estava querendo, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Mais uma duvida, Existe algum outro codigo para identificar o p-value das variaveis??

Comment: Só rodar os testes de significância diretamente.usando `chi2()`